# How to properly locally 'deploy' a Python based server application for development?

Tags: python, web-services, webserver, setuptools, development-environment

A pretty large Python based project I'm working on has to deal with a situation some of you might know:
you have a local checkout which your server can *not* be run from (history), you alter a couple of files, e.g. by editing or `git`-operations and then you want to locally 'patch' a running server residing at a different location of the file system.

[Local Checkout, e.g. `/home/me/project`]  = deploy => [Running Environment, e.g. `/opt/project`]

The 'deployment' process might have to run arbitrary build scripts, copy modified files, maybe restart a running service and so on.

Note that I'm not talking about CI or web-deployment - it's more like you change something on your source files and want to know if it runs (locally).

Currently we do this with a self-grown hierarchy scripts and want to improve this approach, e.g. with a `make`-based approach.

Personally I dislike `make` for Python projects for a couple of reasons, but in principle the thing I'm looking for could be done with `make`, i.e. it detects modifications, knows dependencies and it can do arbitrary stuff to meet the dependencies.
I'm now wondering if there isn't something like `make` for Python projects with same basic features as `make` but with 'Python-awareness' (Python binding, nice handling of command line args, etc).

Has this kind of 'deploy my site for development'-process a name I should know? I'm not asking what program I should use but how I should inform myself (examples are very welcome though)

Comment: Without knowing exactly the full details your project requires, this question is overly broad and thus practically impossible to answer. Namely, what kind of project is this? Web application stack? Database application? Does it need to interface with C extensions? Does the deployment process involve the creation of deployable artifact images (e.g. VMware/VirtualBox/AMI for deployment onto AWS EC2)?

Comment: If you are looking for a specific name or term you might want to search, this might be a DevOps role, or if you are looking into automating the above process (after it has been specified), this may be a CI/CD (Continuous Integration/Continuous Delivery) pipeline that need to be built.

Comment: A deployment should have a configuration specific to the environment. Then you checkout the code, maybe install dependencies and run it. If you have to run make and patch code you are not heading in the right direction.

Comment: I don't want to disagree - usually what I _want_ to do is check out and run as you propose. Currently this is not possible for us and not easily changeable. So what I have is a 'copy' of most of the project structure at some other place and I have to 'update' this copy to changes I make to the checkout.